# FE`symbols that remain in notebook internals even after removing them and SaveDefinitions->True issue

Tags: programming

How does one clear the notebook from symbols that remain in it after an edit session?

Comment: At risk of asking the obvious, have you deleted the dynamic Manipulate objects from the Notebook, saved it, and reopened it?

Comment: In what part of the Notebook file do these FE`* symbol names appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try evaluating this *in a copy of the Notebook* with all the dynamic objects first deleted, then save and examine the Notebook file:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
  PrivateNotebookOptions->{"FileContents"->{"NotebookData"}, "FileOutlineCache"->False}
]
```

Comment: @Nasser I am pleased that this seems to have (nearly) fixed the problem, as it was a bit of a shot in the dark.  These settings as I understand them tell *Mathematica* to save only the bare minimum of data to the .nb file.  By default it uses headers, footers, and cache information, which usually help with various things like version detection and backward compatibility, and speed up opening large .nb files.  Here they apparently were mucking things up.  You should try using only the setting `"FileOutlineCache"->False` as I suspect that is the more likely culprit.

Comment: @Nasser You should only need to evaluate this once in the notebook (or set the same options using the Options Inspector) and then save the file.  From that time on *Mathematica* should save the file without cache or headers (again, headers are useful so I suggest you try it with only the `"FileOutlineCache"` setting).  Alternatively you could evaluate this only before saving a copy to upload.